# Translating "the price of independence" into French

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

If you translated the phrase "the price of independence" very literally into French, would it have any meaning for a native speaker? Or is there some idiom that better conveys the meaning?

Comment: "le prix de l'indépendance" works fine for me!

Comment: It may depend on the context, so you may want to give some more context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depend of what you mean by "independance", if you mean more like freedom (from something or just Freedom) or being able to provide for yourself and not to respond to anyone.
So if it's freedom you translate it to "le prix de la liberté" (very commonly used phrasing in french), if it's providing for themself you can translate it literally by "le prix de l'indépendance".

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I appreciate the clarification on the subtle differences in context.